# Error regarding Stripe's capabilities enablement

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I have an account that is created through here

```
    account = stripe.Account.create(
        country="US",
        type="express",
        capabilities={
            "card_payments": {"requested": True},
            "transfers": {"requested": True},
        },
        business_type="individual",
        email=fund_info['email'],
        settings={"payouts": {"schedule": {"interval": "manual"}}},
    )
```

When I call the Stripe checkout method

```
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        line_items=[{
            'name': 'Service',
            'amount': amount,
            'currency': 'usd',
            'quantity': 1,
        }],
        payment_intent_data={
            'application_fee_amount': int(amount * 0.075),
            'transfer_data': {
                'destination': account_id,
            },
        },
        mode='payment',
        success_url='http://localhost:3000/',
        cancel_url='http://localhost:3000/',
    )
```

It returns an error

Your destination account needs to have at least one of the following capabilities enabled: transfers, legacy_payments

I'm wondering I keep getting this error if I have transfers enabled in the capabilities. If I add legacy_payments, I would get an error that it has been deprecated. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Is the status of the Transfer capability of that Express account `active`? You can check the status of the Transfer capability by retrieving the connected account [0] and checking : https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-capabilities-transfers.

Creating the account does not mean that the capabilities are active, the necessary information needs to be provided in order to verify the account (and hence enable those capabilities).

You can refer this guide : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts on how to onboard an Express account, and refer to the test data here : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing.

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/retrieve